# Call a method each time before any other method is called

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class where inside this class is one private method and many public methods. This private method must be called every time before any other method is called.

The simpliest approach would be calling the method in every method, but I don't like this approach. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: would you like to share your code with us ? This could be a design issue...

Comment: I agree with @Steve that this looks like a design issue.  In my experience, if something doesn't feel right or feels like you're torturing a standard way of doing something, then you should re-evaluate your overall design because you're likely introducing a code smell.  E.g. you'll always have to remember to call this method every time you extend your API -- what if you forget?  There are not compiler warnings, and you have a time bomb exception waiting there.  That being said, I also agree with answers that AOP may be the way to go here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be able to do something here with AOP, perhaps via [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/); but unles you are going to do this **lots**, I'd argue in favor of keeping it simple, and just add the extra code.

Of course, it gets more complex if you need polymorphism and need overrides to still call the method **first** (probably involving a public non-virtual method and a protected virtual method):

```
public void Foo() {
    Bar()
    FooCore();
}
protected virtual void FooCore() {...} // default Foo implementation
private void Bar() {...} // your special code
```

Comment: Ahh... compile-time metaprogramming in C#. It will be a wonderful day when that arrives.

Answer (score 5):

This is a typical case of [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming). As far as I know, there is no easy way to do this in .NET (except using byte-code enhancement or creation of a derived class at runtime, neither is easy. There are libraries doing it, for instance [spring.net](http://www.springframework.net/). I'm not sure if you really need this.)

I would try to avoid this situation at almost every cost - or call this method if there is really no other way.